# samba not working on one interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, samba, linux-networking

I am going a little crazy trying to get Samba working and would really appreciate some pointers. It's quite possible that I have misconfiged some part of the network configuration too.

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 Server. smbd reports version 3.5.8.

My server has two network interfaces configured. One is the primary interface I usually use (eth0), and there is another which will only be used for samba (eth3).

I can always get to the server via eth0, and it works perfectly. However, eth3 just refuses to work. I've experimented with these settings in smbd.conf:

> interfaces = eth3
> bind interfaces only = yes

But eth3 still does not work. Any ideas?

More information:

- I can ping eth3
- I can ssh into eth3
- iptables is down
- I can run nmap against eth3 and it reports Samba is listening (so I don't think a switch is blocking ports)
- I've set samba logging to log level 3, but cannot see anything interesting in the samba logs (so maybe its not a samba problem...?)
- nmbd is not running (I don't need it if I'm connecting via the servers IP, right?)
- output of `netstat -tapn | grep smbd`

> tcp        0      0 192.168.0.3:445         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1843/smbd
> tcp        0      0 192.168.0.3:139         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1843/smbd
> tcp6       0      0 fe80::b699:baff:feb:445 :::*                    LISTEN      1843/smbd
> tcp6       0      0 fe80::b699:baff:feb:139 :::*                    LISTEN      1843/smbd

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

On the windows machine, the network card which was connecting to eth0 has "Client for Microsoft Networks" enabled.

The network card which was connecting to eth3 had it disabled.